# nested loop to extract from webelement

Tags: java, loops, selenium, nested

Below nested loop seems to be problematic. I am unable to figure out what is wrong. Can you please take a look and advise?

```
for (int i = 0; i < headers.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < headerlists.size(); j++) {
        System.out.println(hotelid + "|" + headers.get(i).getText() + "|" + headerlists.get(j).getText());
    }
}
```

the output is not as expected. below is the output it prints -

```
713374|Basic amenities|WiFi
Air Conditioner
24h Check in
Restaurant
Bar
Cafe
Room Service
Internet
Business Center
Pool
Gym
713374|Basic amenities|Air Conditioning
Doorman
Express Check-In
Express Check-Out
Housekeeping
Banquet Facility
Doctor on Call
713374|Basic amenities|Air Conditioning
Doorman
Express Check-In
Express Check-Out
Housekeeping
Banquet Facility
Doctor on Call
```

**Edited** - What I am expecting:

```
713374|Basic amenities|WiFi 713374|Basic amenities|Air Conditioner 713374|Basic amenities|24h Check in 713374|Basic amenities|Restaurant 713374|Basic amenities|Bar 713374|Basic amenities|Cafe 713374|Basic amenities|Room Service 713374|Basic amenities|Internet 713374|Basic amenities|Business Center 713374|Basic amenities|Pool 713374|Basic amenities|Gym
```

Comment: What exactly is problematic?

Comment: You see what my println is?

Comment: You would need to show us more code, we do not see any issues in that code, unless the headerlists contain newline

Answer (score 1):

Going by your expected output in the comments, headerLists' data includes unexpected newlines!The selenium code looks fine. From your comments you said basically that headerLists is outputting too much information.

Again, because of unexpected new lines, we want to handle each bit of data from each newline within each node of headerLists, therefore lets split each newline into an array so we can work with it better.

Treat headerList.get(j).getText() as multiline text, separate linebreak using following loop and harness each individual *NewlineData* for each amenity.

```
for(String NewlineData : headerLists.get(j).getText().split("\\n"))
    System.out.printf(Hotelid + NewlineData + " | "); 
}
```

**Before**

> "Air Conditioning
>
> TV
>
> Bathroom
>
> Etc"

**After**

> "71000 Air Conditioning | 71000 TV | 71000 Bathroom | 71000 Etc"

You can use split to separate char delimited string. Break headerLists with newline char into a string array. And reprint each node from string array along with hotel ID again.

**The forloop above with split method is your key, obviously rearrange your output to match what is expected, you may not want to print 71000 TV | 71000 Bathroom, etc.**

Comment: That should be a comment.

Comment: Right! nothing is wrong with my selenium code. that works perfect.... my out put needs to be the combination of both loops...however that is not happening,,,

Comment: below is what I'm expecting...713374|Basic amenities|WiFi
713374|Basic amenities|Air Conditioner
713374|Basic amenities|24h Check in
713374|Basic amenities|Restaurant
713374|Basic amenities|Bar
713374|Basic amenities|Cafe
713374|Basic amenities|Room Service
713374|Basic amenities|Internet
713374|Basic amenities|Business Center
713374|Basic amenities|Pool
713374|Basic amenities|Gym

Answer (score 0):

it seems `headerlists.get(j).getText()` contains `new line`:

you can remove them by using -->

```
replaceAll("\n"," ")); //repalces all new lines with a empty space
```

here is how your code should look like :

```
for (int i = 0; i < headers.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < headerlists.size(); j++) {
        System.out.println(hotelid + "|" + headers.get(i).getText() + "|" + headerlists.get(j).getText().replaceAll("\n"," ");
    }
}
```

Comment: that piece of code (assuming there is no other Threads are  running ) you represented will not be doing that unless has new line

Comment: you can check the size of headerlists as well, I believe the size is 1 for all the records

Comment: Yeah, I think something is wrong  with my headerlist.. i will keep you guys updated if I find anything wrong in that... thank you so much

Comment: Hi Nafas, you were right. the size of headerlists is 1. why is that happening? although on the web, the list is not consolidated...it should ideally be in different indexes... any idea? below is how it is on web....

Comment: div class="col col8">
<h2 id="amenities">Hotel Royal Heritage-30km before Mount Abu Amenities</h2>
<p class="hotelDescription">
<h3>Basic amenities</h3>
<nav>
<ul id="amIconsExpanded" class="amIcons">
<li class="colZero col11">
<span class="amWIFI" rel="tTooltip" title="WiFi" original-title="WiFi"/>
WiFi
</li>
<li class="colZero col11">
<span class="amAC" rel="tTooltip" title="Air Conditioner" original-title="Air Conditioner"/>
Air Conditioner
</li>

Comment: @BharatNanwani r u using jsoup?